# Find the probability distribution of X?

Tags: probability

Suppose Nokia store places 20 of its cell phones on a clearance sale, unknown to anyone 5 of these cell phones are defective. A customer selects 3 cell phones at random for inspection. Let X be the number of defective cell phones in the sample. Find the probability distribution of X?

My attempt:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        P(X=x) & 0.015625 & 0.140625 & 0.421875 & 0.421875 \\
        \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I calculated the values using the binomial distribution: $$
P(X = x) = nCx \ p^{n-x} (1-p)^x$$

Where, $n$=5, $x$=0,1,2,3 and $p$=(.25) [from 5/20]

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: IF $p$ is the probability of detecting a faulty item ('success'), then it should be $\binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$

Comment: @Alex for sampling *with replacement*

Comment: Still, important to point out that even though Binomial is inappropriate, Binomial was mishandled.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not correct.

In particular with only a quarter of the phones defective, getting three defectives out of three in the sample should have a low probability.

A second point is that the customer is presumably looking at three different phones (sampling *without replacement*), so you not be using the binomial distribution.

As an example, the probability of three phones defective, sampling without replacement, is  $${3 \choose 3} \times \frac{5}{20} \times \frac{4}{19} \times \frac{3}{18} \approx 0.00877$$ rather than your ${3 \choose 3}0.25^0 0.75^3 = 0.421875.$

Answer (score 3):

This experiment is described by a [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). For every $0\leqslant k\leqslant 3$,
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{\color{red}{{5\choose k}}\color{green}{{15\choose 3-k}}}{{20\choose 3}}$$
hence
$$
\mathbb P(X=3)=\frac{\color{red}{5\cdot4\cdot3}}{20\cdot19\cdot18},
\qquad
\mathbb P(X=2)=\frac{\color{red}{5\cdot4}\cdot3\cdot\color{green}{15}}{20\cdot19\cdot18},
$$
$$
\mathbb P(X=1)=\frac{\color{red}{5}\cdot3\cdot\color{green}{14\cdot15}}{20\cdot19\cdot18},
\qquad
\mathbb P(X=0)=\frac{\color{green}{13\cdot14\cdot15}}{20\cdot19\cdot18}.$$

Comment: (a) I thought [you preferred hints](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237741/assume-you-toss-a-fair-coin-25-times-how-many-completed-runs-do-you-expect-to-o/237829#237829) rather than the full answer. (b) Your four probabilities do not add up to 1.

Comment: @Henry (a) Maybe so. A naked link to the WP page might have been more educational here. (b) Thanks, misprint corrected.

Comment: OK - I will delete those comments